# DrRacket: big-bang; can "to-draw" accept two functions?

Tags: racket

I'm in the process of making a flashcard program. I want my big-bang to draw two functions:

```
;; Editor -> Image
;; consumes an Editor and produces an image of the pre, a cursor and the post.
    (define (editor-render ed)
       (overlay/align "left"
                      "bottom"
                      (beside (textify (implode (rev (editor-pre ed))))
                               CURSOR
                               (textify (implode (editor-post ed))))
                       SCENE))

;;List-of-words -> Image
;; consumes a list-of-words and produces an image 
    (define (list-render low)
           (above/align "left"
                 (textify2 (first (first low)))))

;; String, List-of-words -> Editor
;; launches the editor given some initial string
    (define (main s low)
         (big-bang (create-editor s "")
         (on-key editor-kh)
         (to-draw (and editor-render (list-render low)))))
```

The list-of-words look for example like this:

```
(cons (cons "hello" (cons "bonjour" empty)) empty)
```

Where the first word is the word that needs to be translated by the user (using the text editor function {which aren't all displayed here})

Therefore, I want to-draw to draw a recursion of the words that need to be translated, and at the same time allow the user to type. But all I tried has not worked...

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't make sense that your `editor-render` and `list-render` will produce different images. You actually want only one image (which might be from several images combined together), not showing a lot of images in the same time.
2. Thing after `to-draw` must be a function, but you provide `(and ...)` which is a `Boolean`, so this definitely doesn't work!

I always think like this to simplify things:

Let a `World` be a state of your animation,

- The function in `to-draw` consumes a `World` and produces an `Image`.
- The function in `on-key` consumes a `World` and a `Key` and produces a `World`.
- The function in `on-tick` consumes a `World` and produces a `World`.
- The function in `stop-when` consumes a `World` and produces a `Boolean`.
- etc.

Note that all `World` must be of the same type. In your case, you are trying to have two different worlds (different types), so it doesn't work because you are allowed to have only one `World`. How to solve the problem? You could combine two worlds together to get one new big world. For example, you could define:

```
(define-struct world (editor words))
```

Now, you could create wrappers to call functions that you have already written:

```
;; my-on-key : World, Key -> World
(define (my-on-key a-world key)
  (make-world (editor-kh (world-editor a-world) key) (world-words a-world)))

;; do the same for on-tick, etc. if you have them

(big-bang (on-key my-on-key) ...) ;; use the new wrappers instead
```

Back to the drawing functions, what you could do instead is that, you will provide an `Image` from `list-render` to `editor-render`, and then `editor-render` will draw things on top of the inputted image instead.

```
;; editor-render : Editor, Image -> Image
;; Draw things on a-image instead of constructing everything from blank
(define (editor-render ed a-image) ...)
```

Now, you could create a wrapper to draw an image:

```
;; my-to-draw : World -> Image
(define (my-to-draw a-world)
   (editor-render (world-editor a-world) (list-render (world-words a-world))))

(big-bang ... (to-draw my-to-draw)) ;; use the new wrapper instead
```